# Fileset directory not excluding properly

Tags: ant

Learning Ant - I'm trying to exclude all files under a certain directory with:

```
<fileset dir="${testclasses.dir}" id="test.files">
  <exclude name="**/directory-to-exclude/*.class"/>
</fileset>
```

and to make sure I excluded correctly, I'm printing out all the classes under that fileset like so:

```
<path id="updated.test.classes.path">
  <fileset dir="${testclasses.dir}"/>
</path>

<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}|   |-- "
             property="echo.path.compile"
             refid="updated.test.classes.path">
</pathconvert>
<echo message="Printing updated class path: ${echo.path.compile}"/>
```

Yet I still see:

```
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$$anon$1.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$$typecreator1$1.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Complex$.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Complex.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Deep$.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Deep.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$LessDeep$.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$LessDeep.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$StrToTime.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Struct$.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass$Struct.class
     [echo] |   |-- /path/to/testfiles/directory-to-exclude/SomeTestClass.class
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the fileset you pre-defined, you want:

```
<path id="updated.test.classes.path">
  <fileset refid="test.files"/>
</path>
```

Note the `refid=` parameter, which makes use of the fileset you defined with the exclusion.

Your actual code

```
<fileset dir="${testclasses.dir}"/>
```

in the path task will simply include all files, as you observed.